# Outlook 2011 suddenly won't activate

Tags: ms-office

We have a task-specific macbook air (sierra) with outlook 2011. Usage and available storage have prevented updating.

Until about a week ago everything was fine. Now outlook isn't activated. When trying to re-activate using Microsoft 365 subscription account it says it cannot reach the server. This suspiciously started on or around the end of June (can't remember exactly when but I'd stab at 30 June 2021). Other Office apps (2016 - word and excel) are also installed and they are still activated and work fine.

Just asking to see if anyone else has seen this or if anyone can confirm that something has happend with Microsoft no longer maintaining activation of Office 2011 for Mac apps.

I realise it is an old version and Sierra is also old and that an upgrade will fix it but, for practical purposes, I'd really like to get it working again until time and disk space permits upgrading the OS.

Comment: So use the phone activation.  It is widely reported hat Microsoft has discontinued the 2011 activation server.

Comment: Office 2011 went end of life in 2017 [along with phone & online support] Office 2016 went end of life in 2020. MS want you to replace them with newer versions.

Comment: I guess you mean June 30th 2021, there's no June 31th :-)

Comment: There is no phone number displayed for phone activation. I found a number by searching, I tried it. Individual I spoke to wanted an activation code from the screen, there isn't one. In the end he cut me off.